# iOS Xode : AVAudioPlayer is not playing WAV file correctly

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I have a WAV file with tones at around 18kHz. The audio is 16-bit PCM mono.

I am using the following function to play the file:

```
func playSound(name: String) {
        let documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let path = documents.appending("/").appending(name)

        let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: path)

        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            guard let player = player else { return }

            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

When I play it on my iOS 10.2 device I hear a series of tones between 1000Hz to 10000Hz. I've analyzed the rendered audio by capturing it and a frequency plot shows that the original content at 18kHz is there, but there are also tones present between 1000Hz to 10000Hz. When I play the same WAV file with VLC or any other desktop audio player, I don't hear the tones (which is expected since they're located around 18kHz). I suspect that the code above isn't loading the data correctly or that the player isn't properly initialized, so I need a seasoned iOS veteran who can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code it might work for you

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("button-09", ofType: "wav"))
        println(alertSound)

        // Removed deprecated use of AVAudioSessionDelegate protocol
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

        var error:NSError?
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you, but I was hoping for an answer to what i might be doing wrong